# Откуда берется символ с кодом 10?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

1. Кто подскажет, почему когда ввожу "я", то она перескакивает сразу на byte?
2. И ни как не могу понять почему у int выводится 10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что нажатие клавиши Enter вводит символ перевода строки, и 10 — это как раз код этого самого символа перевода строки

Comment: @Abakar, пожалуйста, прикладывайте код не скриншотом, а текстом. Тогда участникам сообщества будет проще помочь вам.

Comment: @AbakarKamalov, если один из ответов вам подошёл, отметьте его зелёной галочкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы вводите букву `я` в консоль и нажимаете <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то в [стандартный поток](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) ввода `System.in` попадает два символа: символ `я` с кодом `1103` и символ [перевода строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) с кодом `10`.

Чтобы прогинорировать перевод строки, сделайте дополнительный `read()`:

```java
int i = reader.read();
reader.read(); // пропускаем перенос строки
```

Либо вызовите метод `skip(1)`, чтобы пропустить 1 символ:

```java
int i = reader.read();
reader.skip(1); // пропускаем перенос строки
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вместо метода `read()` метод `readLine()` метод вернёт строку и вы с ней будете делать что хочется и не надо будет делать дополнительных манипуляций с самой переменной `bufferedReader` и пытаться сделать пропуск строки и т.д.

Пример:
`String i = bufferedReader.readLine();`

Если надо сделать из переменной `int` то можно воспользоваться `Integer.parseInt(String);`